# Why won't this simple Java code not pass this test?

Tags: java, arrays

The code seems correct and straight forward to me, I'm using the basic indexOf method for an array i created.

Why won't this code:

```
public int indexOf(X s)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == s)
        {
            return i;
        } 
    }        
    return -1;
}
```

pass this test:

```
@Test
public void testIndexOf()
{
    BetterArray<String> b = new BetterArray<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        b.add("str" + i);

    assertEquals(0, b.indexOf("str0"));
    assertEquals(19, b.indexOf("str19"));
    assertEquals(-1, b.indexOf("not found"));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this test"?

Answer (score 1):

Cause you compare String or any other object equality with `equals()` not with `==`.

> == tests for reference equality.
>
> .equals() tests for value equality.

Read more : [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: so that helped, but the last test failed, the one where it should return -1.